# Can USB port number be used as a port for client server model?

Tags: python, client-server

I want to establish a client-server model between two hardware devices (CANtact). I have plugged both the hardware to my laptop USB ports they appear as /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyACM1 so can these port numbers be used to establish a client-server model between these two hardware devices? What has to be given as Host in the following program?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The USB port does not have an IP address. Instead it has a serial number, but it cannot be used as a host for a websocket connection.